# How to view output for ALL processes simultaneously?

Tags: terminal, process, tail, output

I know that you can connect to various background processes to watch their console output, but is there a way to view the output of all processes at once? Likely it would scroll quickly and be hard to read, but is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can spawn several processes in your shell in the background and then (if they all use their stdout or stderr) you can get **lots** of information intermingled in the console - and by intermingled I mean it can possibly even mix data from several processes in the middle of a line.

What you are probably looking for is logging to a file (system services usually use something in `/var/log`) and then viewing the file(s). There are couple of utilities for this: `tail` (important option `-F`, which monitors the file and prints any lines added), `less` can (in the follow mode) do the same interactively (i.e. you can switch back and forth between following the file and scrolling back). `most` is another interesting file pager utility, `more` is the "classic" one found almost everywhere (even on DOS and Windows).

Last but not the least, `tee` might be of interest - it duplicates its stdin to stdout **and** to a file, which can often come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

If they all write to a logfile, you can use multitail to tail them all simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

All processes?  Most background processes actually intentionally close their file descriptors, and there's no easy way to grab them back or force the process to recognize a new one.

You can watch all the messages to syslog, as others have said, and a lot of user-spawned processes do actually have their output directed somewhere (at least, if you're running a sane X startup environment), so you can watch a lot of them if you know what files to look at.  But for the most part, you can't see the output of ALL non-user processes because they simply don't have anywhere defined to send output.